# Drawer Layout and Tab Layout

Tags: java, android

```
I have an activity : 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.gwel7_000.time.MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Java :

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
      mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
                        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

                        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

                        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
                        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new Frag1(),"Frag 1 ");
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new Frag2(),"Frag 2 ");
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new Frag3(),"Frag 3 ");
```

Which contains a `tab layout` with differents `fragments` inside.

And i have a `navigation drawer` and i want to handle clicks to the drawer menu so it changes this big `activity` which contains all of these smalls `fragments` in the navigation drawer.The problem is that navigation drawer can only Have fragment inside so i don't really know how to do that.

Comment: you want to implement on click of tabs??

Comment: No i want to add my activity which contains all the fragments to the navigation drawer

Comment: Can you use the ViewPager in one of your Fragments and make it contain other Fragments? That's exactly what I did in my app. Just put your `viewPager` in one of your Fragments which are contained in the Drawer.

Comment: @Vucko yeah but i need to change my mainactivity(where there are fragments inside tabs) into a fragment right ?

Comment: Correct. It wont be that big of a deal.